# Magento: translations don't work after adding a new product to my cart

Tags: csv, magento, localization, translation, magento-1.9

First of all, I am not great at Magento. I think I understand all of the basics and maybe a bit more, but I couldn't create a module from scratch for example.

Anyway, I am trying to create an e-commerce website in french, but I can't seem to make the translations work.

**My issue is the following:**

*The french translation seem to be working fine, until I add a product to the cart.*

Once I have done that, the "X product has been added to your cart" shows in english and then the "See my cart" and some other lines go back to english even though they were in french the second before, and I don't know why.

I have tried to add other translation packs but it doesn't seem to change anything.

I suppose it's an issue with the english translation that take priority over the french translation for some reason, but I don't know where to look to solver this issue.

***My magento version:*** 1.9.3 - Community edition

***The theme I'm using:*** [Sebian for magento](https://themeforest.net/item/sebian-multipurpose-responsive-magento-theme/12048448)

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below step.

1. Create a file if not exists. app/design/{package}/{theme}/locale/fr_FR/translate.csv
2. Add this to translate.csv file >> "%s product has been added to your cart","%s YOUR TRANSLATED LINE"
3. Refresh cache from magento and check in frontend
4. But make sure your Sentence must be written in this way

   **$this->__("YOUR SENTENCE")** in phtml file.

Comment: I have tried to find with Windows Grep which files have the sentence '_Was added to your cart'_ and it didn't find anything in any Phtml file in the whole magento folder. I had already done this though (the translate.csv file) and it didn't work.

Comment: Also, if this was the issue it wouldn't be in french before I click on "add to cart", right ?